# How to allow template class instantiation only if the type T derives from type X?

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
};

class A : public X;

class B;

Test<A> a; // OK
Test<B> b; // NOT OK
```

I would like to accomplish something like this.

Maybe this can be accomplished more easily. Basically, what I need it for is this: the template class T should be able to lock a std::mutex member m_mutex in an object of type T if it exists.

Comment: [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) and [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a static assertion and the appropriate [type trait class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Test
{
    static_assert( std::is_base_of<X,T>::value, "T doesn't derive from X!"); 
};
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e53bdc092bf59aee).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`std::is_base_of<>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) with a SFINAE check:

```
template<
    typename T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X, T>::value>::type
>
class Test {
   ...
};
```

Comment: What about the following? Test has a function f() which would perform some action on an object of type T. However, would it be possible for f() to behave differently if T would have some additional characteristics? It would be like some template #ifdef. If this sounds confusing, let's imagine some T's have a member m_mutex and some don't. f() would only lock m_mutex if it exists. If it's not possible check member presence then perhaps those classes would derive from class HasMutex. Is it possible with just one template class and no specialization?

Comment: @NFRCR You have to determine at compile time the traits the a certain type `T` has. This can be done with trait classes, SFINAE, or `static_assert()`. It's not always possible to do it without using specializations. You should read up more on using templates.

Comment: @NFRCR Yes, it's possible to detect presence of data member (by name and type). Whether it's sensible, that's another matter.